# Manipulating row data in CSV file and appending it in a new column using Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, append

I have an csv file consisting of a list of company names.
The goal is to write a code to generate the direct indeed job listing link for each of these companies using the name alone.
The indeed link for the company- "**Company XYZ**" will be - https://www.indeed.com/q-**company**-**XYZ**-jobs.html

The indeed link should be appended to the existing file under the column name **indeed job link**.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have read the list of company names into a Pandas DataFrame, then you can simple do:

```sh
df["indeed_job_link"] = "https://www.indeed.com/q-" + df["company_name"] + "-jobs.html"
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, the company names sometimes are two separate words, that needs to be combined by a "-" symbol when writing out the indeed link. For example - the company name is ABC XYZ , then the indeed link should be  https://www.indeed.com/q-ABC-XYZ-jobs.html. How do I go about that?

Comment: you can just do `df["company_name"].replace(" ", "-")` instead